# How to convert .html page to .aspx masterpage without using Design Manager?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, master-page, aspx, design-manager

I want to convert a .html page to an .aspx masterpage.

I tried to use the conventional method of Design Manager, but realized that I don't have the Design Manager button. I went to check my "site collection features" under site settings, where I have to activate the "sharepoint server publishing infrastructure" feature to access Design Manager, but I realized I don't even have the "sharepoint server publishing infrastructure" feature.

It turns out that I am currently using the SharePoint 2013 foundation edition (the "sharepoint server publishing infrastructure" feature can only be found in SharePoint server 2013 (standard and enterprise)).

Does anyone have any solutions on how to convert my masterpage without using the Design Manager? Or maybe tell me if I can obtain Design manager in SharePoint 2013 foundation?

Answer (score 1):

Branding SharePoint Foundation is a common headache due to the lack of Design Manager. There are possibilities to do it, but they are not through SharePoint's OOTB built-in functionalities.

I'd suggest to have a look at *Starter Master Pages* at http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/. It might be a bit oldish in terms of latest update, but so is SPF! Starter Master Pages is enough well used to have a few existing guides available in the web to guide in the usage.

When I prefer to 'possibilities' in plural, the other ways I can come up with would be more hands-on level editing, but that'd require one to know exactly what needs to be done when doing so. So as it would be for SharePoint Server as well, it's not recommended to be done this way.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a .master page, then copy all the contents from your html to master page. It should work. Now where you have div tag and you are planning to display content from database, place a content placeholder.

[Master Page from Html](https://jasonagraham.wordpress.com/2013/08/27/how-to-convert-an-html-page-into-an-asp-net-master-page/)